# Lane ID in SUMO and Traci vehicle

Tags: omnet++, sumo

Lane ID is defined as a string in the lane ID definition but in the Traci vehicle moveTo() function the argument is defined as a double value. Do we use the Lane ID as a string ( as defined in .net.xml file in SUMO) or as a double value as in Traci vehicle?

Answer (score 0):

The lane ID is a string. There was a typo in the docs.